# Bootstrap 3 Modal Changes from Horizontal to Inline - Resizing Awkwardly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really love how my old form resized in Bootstrap 2.0, however, when converting to 3.0 I've noticed that whenever I shrink the modal, the form information changes from horizontal to inline and becomes spread out. An example can be found here: https://www.cantedpictures.com/9test/

Is there a way to change it so that the modal, when resizing, functions like this:
https://www.cantedpictures.com/donate/

Comment: Show your code in the question!  All of your recent questions are nothing more than links to external sites.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the two modals are to be found in your css media queries.

Comment: [Google has plenty more information on this subject](http://google.com/search?q=css+media+queries)